# Find extrema of 2 variables function

Tags: analysis

I have to find this function extrema
$f(x,y) =  \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ + $y^2 -1$ on $T ={({(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}, x^2 + y^2 \leqslant{9} })}$.
I first calculated the partial derivatives for $x$ and $y$, which gives me :
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = {x\over\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$
and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = {y\over\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} + 2y$
I tried to find critical point but the system has no solution ? How can I do ?

Comment: Do not vandalize your own post when it has answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just notice that:
$$f(x,y)=\underbrace{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}_{\geq 0}+\underbrace{y^2}_{\geq 0}-1\geq -1,\:\:\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$$
and that:
$$f(0,0)=-1$$
So the absolute minimum of the function is $-1$ and it is obtained at the point $(0,0)$.

**Edit:**
If you want to find the global maximum of $f$ subjected to the constraint $$T=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\:|\:x^2+y^2\leq 9\}$$
observe that:
$$f(x,y)=\underbrace{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}_{\leq\sqrt 9=3}+\underbrace{y^2}_{\leq x^2+y^2\leq 9}-1\leq 3+9-1=11,\:\:\forall(x,y)\in T$$
In addition:
$$f(0,3)=f(0,-3)=11$$
So the absolute maximum of $f$ on $T$ is $11$, and it is (only) reached at the points $(0,\pm 3)$.

Comment: Can I find a maximum using the same method ? I forgot to mention that I have to find extrema on T = {(x,y) ∈ R, x^2 + y^2 <= 9}

Comment: @Kenan Big mistake

Comment: @DARK what do you mean ?

Comment: @Kenan Forget about derivatives, and simply ask yourself: if $~x~$ increases and $~y~$ is constant, what happens?  Alternatively, if $~y~$ increases and $~x~$ is constant, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

To find extrema of $f$ on $T=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}| x^2+y^2 \leq 9\}$,

You have found that $(0,0)$ is the only critical point inside $T$.

Consider the boundary of $x^2+y^2=9$,
$$f(x,y)=f(y)=3+y^2-1=y^2+2  \space ; y\in [-3,3]$$

Now $f_y(y)=0 \iff y=0$ follows $(-3,0) $and $(3,0)$ on the boundary.

Corner points $(0,3)$ and $(0,-3)$. Now you have covered every point in an on $T$ so

$f(0,0)=-1(\text{ Absolute Minimum})$,

$f(-3,0)=2,f(3,0)=2,$

$f(0,-3)=11\text{(Absolute Maximum on T)},f(0,-3)=11 \text{(Absolute Maximum on T)}$.